# How to style JFXtras CalendarTimeTextField?

Tags: java, css, jfxtras

I want to style the font of the CalendarTimeTextField Popup control using a CSS File.

The following entry doesn't work for me:

```
.CalendarTimeTextFieldSkin_popup {
     -fx-text-fill: white;
     -fx-font-style: italic;
 }
```

Setting the font-type works, changing text color doesn't.

Thanks for supporting me
GGK

Comment: The popup of course contains just the CalendarPicker, have you tried styling that directly? .CalendarPickerControlSkin { 
 -fx-text-fill: white;
     -fx-font-style: italic;
}

Comment: i did... `.CalendarPicker { 
 -fx-text-fill: white;
 -fx-font-style: italic;
}

.CalendarPickerControlSkin { 
 -fx-text-fill: white;
 -fx-font-style: italic;
}

.CalendarPickerControlSkin_popup { 
 -fx-text-fill: white;
 -fx-font-style: italic;
}

.CalendarTimeTextFieldSkin_popup  {
 -fx-text-fill: white;
 -fx-font-style: italic;
}

.CalendarTimePickerSkin_popup .timeLabel { 
 -fx-text-fill: white;
 -fx-font-style: italic;
}`...but nothing changed

Comment: looks like (https://picload.org/view/dawoaori/10-04-_2018_16-51-55.jpg.html)

Comment: Ahhhh, that text is from the TimePicker! https://github.com/JFXtras/jfxtras/blob/9.0/jfxtras-controls/src/main/resources/jfxtras/internal/scene/control/CalendarTimePicker.css

Comment: `.CalendarTimePickerSkin { 
 -fx-text-fill: white;
 -fx-font-style: italic;
}` sets the font italic...but colore won't change. Probably styling the font color isn't possible?

Comment: I'm a bit busy ATM. Unfortunately JavaFX does not have such a nice CSS application-tree as browsers do. But the text is rendered with a Text node (https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#text) and if I search on the web ()https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/text/jfxpub-text.htm) I see that -fx-stroke: black; is used. Give that a try.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's exactly what I'm looking for. Now I set following code...and it works. `.CalendarTimePickerSkin .timeLabel {
 -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI Semibold";
 -fx-font-size: 15pt;
    -fx-fill: white;

}`

Answer (score 0):

The text is rendered with a Text node (https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#text) so use -fx-fill and/or -fx-stroke.